# Gerador de Imagens

Tags: php

Alguém sabe como criar um código PHP para gerar uma imagem que pela url se passe `image.php?src=logo&width=600&height=600` e o resultado final seja uma imagem com as dimensões especificas e vá busca-la a `imgs/logo.png`.

PS: O formato tem de ser `.png`.

Comment: Não percebi o negativo!

Comment: O negativo é pelo tipo de pergunta. Sim, muita gente sabe criar esse código, mas o ideal é que você tente escrevê-lo primeiro e se encontrar alguma dificuldade nessa atividade, retorne aqui com um problema específico a ser resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa pegar os parâmetros por get e atribuir a tag img do HTML.

Por exemplo. Se sua página é essa "image.php?src=logo&width=600&height=600" o código será:

```
<img src="imgs/<?php echo $_GET['src'] ?>.png" width="<?php echo $_GET['width'] ?>" height="<?php echo $_GET['height'] ?>">
```